# What's a good method for combining data of different deep learning models?

Tags: deep-learning

Suppose I want to predict the probability of a person to buy something. I want to analyze the person image and I can use a convolutional neural network, but I also want to input in my predictive model how many times he bought something, where he goes more frequently and so on. What is a correct way to input in a deep learning model informations from different deep learning models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can merge two different DL model into a big one.

I'm using Keras+Tensorflow for deep learning, and there's an [example](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) about models with multiple inputs(outputs). In this example, tweets are fed into a RNN, while the extra data are fed into a fully-connected layer along with the output of this RNN.

Comment: In general I can choose a model I want to merge informations about different inputs or is there some rules?

Comment: Personally speaking, we might merge different related data into one model, but it's hard to put the earth into a network and ask for predicting the future. More data leads to a good model, along with the difficulty on model training and tuning.